# Direct to voicemail turns off on its own

Tags: nexus-5x, voicemail

I have a "spam" contact which is set to "route to voicemail" right away. (See [How to gracefully block calls](https://www.faqforge.com/android/gracefully-ignoreblock-calls-android-marshmallow/) for an example)

This setting frequently turns off on its own, so calls go through anyway.

Why would that be the case? What can I do about it? I'm using my carriers ([Three/Hutchison 3G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hutchison_3G)) normal voicemail service.

Nexus 5X, stock android 7.1.2.

Comment: @xavier_fakerat Are you suggesting that the carrier can arbitrarily flip settings on my phone? (The was has not been provided to me by the carrier), or are you saying that the contact setting is expected to be respected by the carrier, and they don't? I'm not sure what I'd be asking the carrier?

Comment: @xavier_fakerat I've added a link that contains detailed instructions of pictures showing how this works. I'm not sure if that helps to clear anything up. My comment above was supposed to say "The phone was not provided to me by the carrier". The voicemail service is not custmized in any way, sorry if my previous comment gave that impression. I'm using only what's already in android for this, no third party software installed.

Comment: Just another question...I understand the Google phone app (a.k.a dialer) has this voicemail functionality, but which voicemail service does it use? Is it Google voice or carrier e.g T-Mobile?. Its a bit difficult to reproduce a similar scenario if these details are missing. Probably I would say an issue with the dialer app, of which I suggest clearing its cache and see if there is difference and perhaps checking in battery optimisation settings.

Comment: @xavier_fakerat Sorry, I didn't realize that was important information, but I've added it now. I've also tried to clear the cache for the dialer to see if it helps. Couldn't find anything related to battery saving that might be relevant. Are you thinking that a low battery mode prevents the phone from rejecting the call on time, so that the call goes through?

Comment: Not really but from Android point of view, certain applications which use a lot of resources tend to get killed in low memory conditions, do it may be a possibility that at times it may be killed, (thus non functional) but restored when resources are okay....its just a possibility. So I think its better not to overlook these petty issues. Secondly pertaining to our situation I suspect if we the voicemail service provider is known, we may exclude guesses as what it is the problem cause, I have'd many users xomplain of disruption of their voicemail service through their carriers, or

Comment: Its issue with the device itself as Nexus has ability to block calls at sustem level, but I am not too sure how the calls are later retrieved, so perhaps congestion with already saved calls? These are just scenarios Im imagining in troubleshooting the issue, but now I do not have conclusive evidence on cause. I have escalated the question with an upvote perhaps other users may join to help

Comment: Using [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut),  see if you can create a shortcut to *route to voicemail*. If you can, then you can think of automating enabling the setting everytime you get a call from that number

Comment: Did you manage to solve this matter?